# to collect in a list all that has the same count of items in the list and to creat a dictionary with that

Tags: python, dictionary

For a given list of words such as

```
meyveler=["elma","armut","şeftali","kiraz","muz","erik","üzüm","nar","karpuz","kavun","kivi","havuç","portakal","mandalina"]
```

I want to create a dictionary that displays words with equal
letter numbers in the same groups, as in the example output below.

```
{ 3:['muz','nar'], 4: [‘kivi’,'elma','erik','üzüm' ] 5: [‘havuç’, 'armut','kiraz','kavun'] 6: [‘karpuz’], 7: [‘şeftali’], 8: [‘portakal’], 9: [‘mandalina’] }
```

Here is a code snippet that shows what I've tried so far:

```
n={}
t=set()
for i in meyveler:
    t.add(len(i))
p=list(t)
for i in meyveler:
    q=0
    while q<len(p):
        if len(i)==p[q]:
            n.update({p[q]:[i]})
        q+=1
print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making things a little more complex that you need to. Just loop through the set of words and append to the list (or create the list if you haven't seen the count yet). [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) is handy for this. You could also use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
meyveler=["elma","armut","şeftali","kiraz","muz","erik","üzüm","nar","karpuz","kavun","kivi","havuç","portakal","mandalina"] 

counts = {}
for word in set(meyveler):
    counts.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)

print(counts)
# {7: ['şeftali'], 4: ['elma', 'üzüm', 'kivi', 'erik'], 5: ['havuç', 'kavun', 'armut', 'kiraz'], 3: ['nar', 'muz'], 8: ['portakal'], 6: ['karpuz'], 9: ['mandalina']}
```

**Edit:**
I am passing the original list to `set()` because I saw your use of `set()` and thought you might be concerned about duplicates. As the comments mention, you could use sets instead of lists in the dictionary (`counts.setdefault(len(word), set())`). Or, if you're not concerned with duplicates, just iterate over the list (`for word in meyveler:` ...).

Comment: @Matiiss I didn't know if there would be duplicate words and wanted to avoid something like `3: ['nar', 'muz', 'nar']`

Comment: but then you could set the default value to a set instead, that would be more efficient

Comment: @Matiiss, but then you end up with sets instead of lists. I did this mostly because I saw the OP's use of set and assumed they were using it because of this concern. Obviously I could be wrong about that.

Comment: there wouldn't be much difference between having a list or a set in the dictionary, considering that list would really be needed for accessing specific indexes which doesn't seem to be the case here since the initial list is converted to a set anyways so any order is lost too, but if OP wants this way then sure

Comment: @Matiiss I agree, but after you've been here a while you realize that you get downvotes because people say "The op wanted lists, this doesn't match the requirements". I appreciate your comments, but on SO, it would be just as likely if I didn't use a set for someone to object that my code doesn't properly handle duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be substantially simplified -- this snippet reads in one word at a time and inserts it into the appropriate list (creating new key-value pairs if a word has a length we haven't seen at that point):

```py
meyveler=["elma","armut","şeftali","kiraz","muz","erik","üzüm","nar","karpuz","kavun","kivi","havuç","portakal","mandalina"] 
n = {}
for word in meyveler:
    if len(word) not in n:
        n[len(word)] = []
    n[len(word)].append(word)
    
print(n)
```

Comment: you could avoid calling that function 3 times, by just assigning the returned value to a variable and referencing that variable instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't produce your desired dictionary because in every iteration, you are updating `n` instead of adding to its values. If you replace

```
n.update({p[q]:[i]})
```

with

```
n[p[q]] = n.get(p[q], []) + [i]
```

your code will work as expected. But as the other answers suggest, it's far better to iterate over `meyveler` once and decide on the spot where to place the word in `n` depending on its length, instead using 2 iterations (or in your case double iterations). That's why it's a better solution to use methods like `collections.defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault` or `dict.get` where you can set a default value (such as empty lists) for keys yet to be defined and just append to them.

Here's one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
n = defaultdict(list)
for w in meyveler:
    n[len(w)].append(w)
```

Here's another (this method finds the lengths and them iterates over the list again similar to your method but you'll find that this is slower than the other methods):

```
n = {}
for length, word in zip(map(len, meyveler), meyveler):
    n[length] = n.get(length, []) + [word]
```

Output:

```
{4: ['elma', 'erik', 'üzüm', 'kivi'],
 5: ['armut', 'kiraz', 'kavun', 'havuç'],
 7: ['şeftali'],
 3: ['muz', 'nar'],
 6: ['karpuz'],
 8: ['portakal'],
 9: ['mandalina']}
```